# Create a barplot in R with 2 bars

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'd like to create a barplot comparing the x'axis:

This is my dataframe:

| group | EMSE_2012 | EMSE_2018 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Suicidio | 16.6 | 21.5 |
| Soledad | 9.1 | 16.3 |
| Preocupacion | 8.4 | 12.7 |
| Sin Amigos | 5.5 | 5.2 |

I need to compare each column in the same bar, in order to have 4 groups of 8 columns. I hope to be clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' and use `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -group) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = group, y = value, fill = name)) + 
      geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = c("Suicidio", "Soledad", "Preocupacion", 
"Sin Amigos"), EMSE_2012 = c(16.6, 9.1, 8.4, 5.5), EMSE_2018 = c(21.5, 
16.3, 12.7, 5.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

Comment: Genious!! It worked! Thank you, a loot!!